# Errors relating to date data type using Pentaho Spoon

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am reading a CSV file with information about tweets using Spoon. There is a `created_at` field at which time the tweet was sent.

However, the format is varied, with some examples being `'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', 'MM/dd HH:mm' and 'MM-dd'`, which is the reason I am getting errors.

What I would like to do is to use the date data type and still capture all the data. I thought about using the `strings cut` step or just changing the data type to `string` and increasing the length of the characters, but it may come at a cost of losing data. What else could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just read them as `String` with no size.

According to your use case you may not have to convert them explicitly to a Date (lazy evaluation).

If you have to convert them to a Date, try a `Javascript` step, for which the `new Date()` is rather tolerant.

Otherwise you may test the format with a Regular Expression. If I take the format your give: `'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', 'MM/dd HH:mm' and 'MM-dd'`, this will code something like:

```
var created_date;
if(regex = created_at.match(/(\d\d\d\d\)\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d)/))
    created_date = new Date(regex[1], regex[2], regex[3], regex[4], regex[5]);
if(regex = created_at.match(/(\d\d\d\d\)\-(\d\d)\-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d)/))
    created_date = new Date(regex[1], regex[2], regex[3], regex[4], regex[5]);
if(regex = created_at.match(/(\d\d)\/(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d)/))
    created_date = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), regex[1], regex[2], regex[3], regex[4]);
if(regex = created_at.match(/(\d\d)\/(\d\d))
    created_date = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), regex[1], regex[2]);
```

Then save `created_data` with the `Date` data type. Check for null values in the output flow until all the formats are defined.

Comment: But if I wanted to analyse the data with the `created_at` field, reading them as a string will  not be of much use. My task is to be done predominantly using Spoon, so I would use JavaScript or Java as a last resort.

Comment: Greetings goes to tweeter, not spoon. Use the `Modified Javascript Value` step in spoon. Much more easy than the `User Defined Java Class`. I updated my answer accordingly.